# How use middleware for differentiate between normal user and admin

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have created a middleware the purpose of this middleware is that to differentiate between admin and normal user but it is not working properly whatever user or admin come it redirect to the same page and my condition is not working and I am using the same table for normal user and admin. I am using laravel 5.5 for this.

```
if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
```

Comment: the think that i want to highlight that the if condition is not working i have checked it but why whats wrong in if condition? and how this statement works i just copy and paste this condition please guide me thanks in advance.:)

Comment: did you create a column/property on your user model/database `isAdmin`?

Comment: yes i have. i have checked it on other properties like name email but all give me the same result it not just about 'isAdmin ' property all properties are not working is this particular case.

Comment: probably Auth::user() is null, check that your middleware run after the auth middleware

Comment: can u please explain this?

Comment: I think you have configured your middleware in Kernel.php to run before the auth middleware, if that is the case Auth::user() return a null value

Answer (score 0):

okay follow my guide

1. run this comment in your terminal "make sure cd to ur project"

> php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin

2. Edit isAdmin file

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
    if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
           return $next($request);
    }

   return redirect('/');
   }
3. Add it to the routeMiddleware array in your kernel file by opening app/Http/Kernel.php

   'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
4. Apply the middleware to your route

   Route::get('admin_area', ['middleware' => 'admin', function () {
   //
   }]);

Hop this is work for you

Answer (score 0):

Open Middleware -> RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

1.Remove this code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

2.copy/paste this one

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }else{
        return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('flash_message_error','Please login to access');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```